Rails 8 ActiveAdmin: SCSS not loading, throws "active_admin.css file does not exist"
I’m using Rails 8 with ActiveAdmin and trying to integrate Tailwind CSS in the admin interface. I created a custom SCSS file (active_admin.scss) inside app/assets/stylesheets/ but I’m facing the following issues:
ActiveAdmin does not load the SCSS file, even though it exists.
I get an error stating "active_admin.css file does not exist" or similar message when the page is rendered.
After generating an active_admin.css file, CSS is not loading properly, and only plain HTML is displayed on the page with no styles applied.
Here’s what I have done so far:

Renamed active_admin.css to active_admin.scss to use Tailwind.
Added @tailwind base;, @tailwind components;, and @tailwind utilities; inside active_admin.scss.
Precompiled the assets with rails assets:precompile


I also facing the same issue, I think it's because of new Rail 8 use propshaft  but active_admin still using sprocket. But haven't come up with any solution yet.
